# Has someone recent and trusted news about Linq to XSD?

Tags: linq, xsd

or is there a project with the same goals? maybe with IQueryable provider ready to use.. am I asking too much?

Comment: MS XML Team moved project Codeplex : http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/
as announced here : http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2009/06/03/linq-to-xsd-now-available-on-codeplex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

XmlGen# is a project that I've started that has similar goals to LINQ to XSD and .NET's built-in xsd.exe utility.

[Click here for link to XmlGen# hosted on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/xmlgensharp)

Comment: Hi,Kevin
Nice to find you on SO. On April,16th I left a comment on your blog:

http://www.kevindietz.com/CommentView,guid,6cbec313-9d70-467e-8dbf-e8747d341038.aspx#commentstart

Comment: Hi Kevin, I didn't know about this project. Checking it out now. Does XmlGen# have support for nillables?